# WebView inside PopupWindow in android

Tags: popupwindow

**Usecase :**

```
I am writing code for browser, in that I want to display WebView
content inside a PopupWindow. That is WebView should not be part of
MainApplication window.
```

**Details:**

- WebView can be placed inside android Dialog (already tested it), but problem is Dialog will be part of MainApplication window eventhough it looks like separate window for user.
- With PopupWindow, WebView is getting displayed for a moment, after that it is getting disappeared.

Popup Window layout details as below

```
{
        popUp = new PopupWindow(this);
        layout = new LinearLayout(this);
        mainLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        but = new Button(this);
        but.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    popUp.showAtLocation(mainLayout, Gravity.CENTER, 10, 10);
                    popUp.update(0, 0, 1280, 1024);
            }
         }
        flayout = new FrameLayout(this);
        mwebview = new WebView(this);
        flayout.addView(mwebview);
        params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        layout.addView(flayout, params);

        popUp.setContentView(layout);
        mainLayout.addView(but, params);
        setContentView(mainLayout);

       === webview init done here===
}
```

Really need your suggestions on this.

Comment: Did you get solution for this? Can you please share me that?